# Is Eren immortal?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I don't know why, but while I'm reading fanfiction and other things I notice that people sometimes quote how no one wants Eren to die because he's "the key to humanity". I've always thought he was immortal so that confused me.

Because of Eren's Titan skills, he heals fast, which seems kind of immortal.

Does Eren have a weak spot that will kill him?

Also note that Levi said in an episode that there is no way for Eren to die (at least as of that point, given that no one has found a way to do so), but there is a way to permanently injure him. So does that make him immortal? And why do people say he's not immortal like he will die or something?

Comment: Since Eren has not died, I don't think we can say for sure. But I would suspect that cutting him from his titan form and decapitating him would be effective enough.

Comment: Isn't the back of the neck of every titan their weak spot. Even that leg hitting girl( with all the characters dying , I can't remember every name :( ), the first lady titan, was covering her neck portion even after getting captured.

Comment: Well Eren is protected by the Protagonist law :/

Comment: Well he only heals when he isn't moving (or being attacked) He wasn't healing when the other titans were eating him. He had a stake going through him in his chest (human not titan body) You just don't know, one minute he is stronger then normal, then healing? So weird....

Comment: I don't really have an answer. Because while he is a shifter, it is because of Grisha's experiments (supposedly). So while it is possible he is the same as the others (same weaknesses on the back of the neck), it is also possible there are differences. We've already seen one difference. The Coordinate Ability. The only other two to show that is the Ape Titan (who is in a class of its own) and the Mysterious Woman who may turn out to not be a titan at all for all we know.

Comment: No he is not immortal. I mean yes he can regenerate fast, and no one particularly really knows the extent of how he can regenerate maybe he can grow another body I honestly don't know. You shouldn't rule out the fact that their are other ways to die. Like if he dies of old age. If you mean more in the recent terms, then it is possible that Eren's healing terms are only when it's still attach to him. I really don't actually know how much he can regenerate but I feel it's safe to assume if you cut his head off he most likely will not regenerate.

Comment: While Eren *could* die, he won't because of plot [armor](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlotArmor). As Braiam mentions, there's no reason or evidence to support that he is actually, within the context of the story, invincible. He just survives cause the story requires him too.

Comment: Erin's father was a titan shifter as well... and titan shifters gain abilities from others who they eat. His father was said to have eaten someone who's titan ability was "*Immortal*" but we have yet to see what that actually was, or if it is truly immortality. This then passed on to Erin when his father supposedly made him eat him, transferring the abilities to his son.

Comment: Don't forget, immortal =/= invincible.

Comment: Abilities of shifter titans allow them to survive even in most unpleasant conditions, like brain damage to human "core". But according to recent chapters, it is still possible to kill them, dealing massive damage. I suppose, beheading will kill them, if some tricks will not be applied.

Answer (score 12):

Lets compile what we know.

Eren up until now has show none of the signs of an immortal ability but only high regenerative abilities. He has been capable of replacing/regenerating lost limbs and recover his formal facial features. Eren hasn't been hit with any critical injury that would cause any normal human dead.

Eren is only a *die hard* character due his regenerative abilities but it's safe to assume that if his head is blown off or his heart is screwed over he *could* die.

Answer (score 4):

**No**, Eren is not immortal and can be killed. **Eren isn't different from other Titan Shifter**. If anything he is actually weaker than most of the Titan Shifter we have seen, yet some have died. Out of the seven introduced Titan Shifter, two were killed so far, so it is safe to say that Eren has the same weakness as they had and that he can be killed.

**Eren is a Titan** and will always be a Titan. Titans can all regenerate quickly, but the only weaknesses known so far is **destroying their necks** beyond repair. We know that not only regular Titans have this weakness, but Titan Shifter also have this weakness as we can see Annie protect her neck by all means.

If anything, I'd say **the Armored Titan might be immortal** as we haven't seen a way to pierce the armored skin so far. He can be killed in human form, but if he can transform fast enough for it to happen, we have yet to find a way to stop him.

Comment: The ritual to transfer the Coordinate Power require imbibing the spinal fluid of the current bearer (that is what Rod Reiss tried to do to Eren). So you are correct that the titan regeneration do not work on the back of the necks (maybe they cannot regenerate spinal/neural tissue).

Comment: The armored titan will fall soon. The 3D maneuvering R&D will develop gas powered vibro blades when story calls for it.

Comment: @mindwin i guess this answer needs updating too, seeing how we have seen the armored titan receive a pretty bad beating recently. Just by brute force on top of that.

Comment: I had not read the most recent chapters, my two jobs are killing my Otaku time.

Comment: Didn't they kill the armored guy in the last chapters?

Comment: @Gallifreian No they did not. They killed Bertolt instead. I see what you mean though, I will update my answer according to the new developments tonight.

Comment: @PeterRaeves  -  oh, well. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: Agree that needs to be updated, we've seen the armored titan armor being broken in the anime in season 2

Answer (score 3):

No, he is not.

> Because he will die if his spinal cord is badly damaged. He could also die if he was eaten by another titan. And also a titan shifter could only live 13 years after becoming a shifter. This is called The Curse of Ymir.

Comment: Then, how was jaw titan dormant in earth for 60 years?

Comment: do you mean ymir? she was a mindless titan before she turned into a jaw titan by eating marcel galliard. it's possible for a mindless titan to live for 60 years.

Comment: No, soon after she woke up from earth, she had shown signs of intelligence.When did she ate marcel?

Comment: woke up from earth? could you please mention which chapter was it? i can't really remember. she ate marcell when he was in the middle of the way to go to shinganshina with reiner, bertholdt and annie.

Answer (score 2):

It has yet to be determined, however information for Season 2 assuming they follow the manga suggest that Titan Shifters may be considerably long lived or age differently after reaching maturity. Eren at present has only demonstrated the ability to regenerate and Annie showed some signs of fearing death, so its unlikely that Titan Shifters are outright Immortal. Plus the Colossal Titan chose to shift and escape suggesting Eren could have killed him.

Answer (score 1):

Eren is not immortal. In Chapter 65: Dreams and Curses, Krista Lenz's (Historia Reiss') father tells her

> to turn into Titan and eat Eren.

And below is the part of manga from Chapter 66: Wish:

> [image: chapter-66]

I think this will explain that Eren is not immortal and can be killed.